# PHPUnit mock object with strict parameter comparison

Tags: php, phpunit

With a mock object, I am able to quickly verify if a passed parameter of a method is equal to my original object thanks to the `with` method:

```php
$hosting = new Hosting();

$this->entityManager
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('persist')
    ->with($hosting)
;
$this->persister->persist($hosting);
```

However, this test is not fully reliable. If I replace the `$hosting` parameter from the internal `EntityManager::persist` method by a `new Hosting()` instance, the test will pass when it should not.

To fix that, I have to put a custom callback:

```php
$this->entityManager
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('persist')
    ->with(self::callback(static fn ($parameter) => $parameter === $hosting))
;
```

It works like a charm. However, I would like to have a simpler method call. Something like `withSame`.

I search on the official documentation without success.

Do we have a simpler way to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simpler way using the PHPUnit assert static function:

```php
$this->entityManager
    ->expects($this->once())
    ->method('persist')
    ->with(self::identicalTo($hosting))
;
```

I found that by digging on the code where the `callback` function is defined. There are many more!